# My ajax request does not return data but return an empty array

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to pass data from js to php through ajax, but the output is an empty array even if I passed some data . please help with this.

````
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
  <script>
      $.ajax({
        url:"trialphp.php",
        data:{name:"bhanu",
              caste:"arora"},
        success:function(res){
          console.log(res);
        }
      });
    </script>
</html>```

**trialphp.php**
<?php
echo(json_encode($_GET));
?>
````

Comment: where is method? `$.ajax({   url:"trialphp.php",method:'POST'`  or `method:'GET'` and add after method `type:'json'`

Comment: Well your code works fine. So not sure what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define which `method` you are going to use for this ajax request as well as you need to define your `dataType`.

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url:"trialphp.php",
    method: 'get', //or post
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{name:"bhanu",
          caste:"arora"},
    success:function(res){
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
</script>
```

in your case you're returning an array so `dataType` should be `json`, if you want to echo a non array variable then type `text` in `dataType`

Comment: The method is GET by default.

Comment: you're right @TimBrownlaw, it is just for demonstration to define which method to use, so I wrote a comment in `method`

Comment: Thanks to both of you! But I am using it in mobile , any suggestion from you how to run Ajax successfully  in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer but a demonstration that your code works.

I setup your code as follows...

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is an AJAX Test</h1>
</body>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "trialphp.php",
        data: {
            name: "bhanu",
            caste: "arora",
            itworks:"success"
        },
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

And **trialphp.php** is

```
<?php
echo(json_encode($_GET));
```

And in my console under firefox I get...

```
{"name":"bhanu","caste":"arora","itworks":"success"}
```